# Convert from .txt to .csv file with horizontal orientation python

Tags: python, csv, txt

I have a .txt file which looks like this:
[txt file example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQS9p.png)

I want to make a .csv file where in the first row will the names be written (keys, values) and below that the values of each names. It should be something like this:
[csv file example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhBbH.png)

Comment: you have one text file or two for keys and values?  update question

Comment: one text file and the example above is exactly what is inside.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import csv

k = ['0.0', '0.25', '0.5', '0.75', '1.0', '1.25']
v = [5, 46, 597, 2882, 5398, 4]

with open("output.csv", 'w') as file:
    wr = csv.writer(file)
    wr.writerow(["keys", "values"])
    for row in zip(k, v):
        wr.writerow(row)
```

Output of the `.csv` file:

```
keys,values
0.0,5
0.25,46
0.5,597
0.75,2882
1.0,5398
1.25,4
```

EDIT: This is working code (i.e. a total hack) for the sample data from that file you showed. I'm parsing it as is, so you might have to edit the code if the data changes.

Contents of `data.txt`:

```
keys(['0.0', '10.0', '20.0', '30.0'])
values([43430, 156, 3, 1])
```

Code:

```
import ast
import csv
import re

p = re.compile(r"\((.*)\)")

with open("data.txt") as f:
    data = f.readlines()

parsed = [
    ast.literal_eval(
        ''.join(i for i in re.search(p, l.strip()).groups())
    ) for l in data
]


with open("output.csv", 'w') as file:
    wr = csv.writer(file)
    wr.writerow(["keys", "values"])
    for row in zip(*parsed):
        wr.writerow(row)
```

The contents of the `output.csv` file.

```
keys,values
0.0,43430
10.0,156
20.0,3
30.0,1
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, but this is hard-cored. The above was just a copy what was inside a small .txt file. It can be much larger with a lot of different names and values.

Comment: Show me an example of that file, a couple of lines would just fine.

Comment: keys(['0.0', '10.0', '20.0', '30.0'])

values([43430, 156, 3, 1])

This is exactly what is inside of one small .txt file

Comment: Is it on one line? Are these two lines?

Comment: 2 lines, but in the comment it is impossible to make 2 lines. Sorry.

Comment: @Davidoff you're welcome. If you find the answer useful, please upvote and/or accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Since txt file is in two lines once imported it is appears as string so here is what i would do

```
import re 
f = open('textfile.txt', 'r')

#new output file
new_csv = open('output.csv' 'w')

text = f.read()
ks = text.split('\n')[0]
ve = text.split('\n')[1]
keys = re.findall(r"'(.+?)'", str(ks))
values = re.findall(r"'(.+?)'", str(ve))
for key, value in zip(keys, values):
    new_csv.write(key+','+value+'\n')

new_csv.close()
```